# 使っているデバイスによってbackground-sizeを変えたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, scss

**やりたいこと**
作っているアプリ内で，background-sizeがいまいちいい感じに決まりません．そこで，”pcならcontain, それ以外ならcover”みたいなことをやりたいです．

**コード例**
**pages.scss**

```
  .top-main {
  padding: 200px 0 200px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  /*background-image: image-url('app/assets/images/canva.jpg'); */
  background-image: url('zero-home.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

こんな感じで今は書いているのですが，この `”background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;”` をどうにかしてサイズに応じてcoverに変えたり出来たらいいなと思っています．

**追記分**
**pages.scss** （トップページのscssです）

```
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .top-main {
    background-image: url('zero-home.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .devise {
    background-image: url('zero-home.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 560px) {
  .top-main {
    background-image: url('zero-home.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
  }
  .devise {
    background-image: url('zero-home.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

メディアクエリを使ってブラウザーのビューポートの幅で切り替えるのが一般的です。

たとえばスマートフォン用の指定は下記を追加します

```css
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .top-main {
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

Comment: 例えば、「タブレット用（タブレット以上の画面サイズ用）」と「それ以下用」となった二通りで場合分けしたい場合、`@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .top-main {
    background-size: cover;
  }
} `と`@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .top-main {
    background-size: contain;
  }
}`と２つ書くということでよろしいですか？

Comment: if-elseみたいな分岐は出来ないのかなと思ったので聞いてみました

Comment: 複雑な条件文も書けるけど使いません。
else はありませんが not があります。

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

よく使われる常套句はこんな感じです

`@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }`

`@media (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }`

`@media (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }`

値の意味はここを参照してみてください https://getbootstrap.jp/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#max-width

Comment: ちなみに 0.02 を引いているのは Safari のバグを回避するためだったのですが、最近はつけない風潮みたいです https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#overview

Comment: あ、bootstrap の記事は僕も確認しました！列挙する形で書くのが主流なんですね、やってみます！0.02引いてるのはそういうことだったんですね！わかりました！

Comment: 追記分みたいな感じで書いてみたんですが，いまいち出来てない気がします．どこかおかしかったりしますか？